Twitter ingestion error with Tweepy v3.10.0 and Twitter API - Error 403 and Py4JJavaError
I'm encountering a 403 error when ingesting tweets using Tweepy v3.10.0 and Twitter API. The Search API works fine in Postman, indicating an authentication issue within the notebook.
Here's my Twitter authentication code:
Notebook Ingest Process Pweets
Additional Information:

This project utilizes Spark for tweet ingestion.
The full error is as follows:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2907.throwExceptionIfHave.
: com.microsoft.spark.notebook.msutils.NotebookExecutionException: Twitter error response: status code = 403

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this issue.
I've tried the Search API using Twitter's Postman Collection, and it works fine.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
